# Missing columns while importing excel data into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, os.execl

I am moving Excel data into SQL Server 2012 using the Import/Export wizard.

The Excel sheet has 377 columns, but when I am importing the file into SQL Server, only 255 columns are appearing in the table. Where are the rest of the columns?

Comment: Possible error during the convert of datas. This is very general qeustion, we need more detail. Structure of your table and what data are you trying to insert

Comment: all the columns has int or float data.

Comment: This seems to be known problem. I failed at finding official solution, but here is a blog [detailing a procedure to overcome the problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/01/22/importing-excel-2010-data-into-sql-server.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a limitation of the ACE driver so not easy to overcome.

An easy solution that I see is to open up the Excel sheet in Excel, then save as CSV.  Then use the Import wizard to import the CSV.

I'm not sure if you're aware of this, but the Import/Export wizard is actually using SSIS.  In one of the last screens, you have the option to save the SSIS package (.dtsx).

To get the workaround with the names ranges to work, you'll first need to import the two ranges in two separate tables and then join them together to fill up the final table.

Maybe this helps as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2011/01/22/importing-excel-2010-data-into-sql-server.aspx

Comment: which one you used? two separated imports or the .csv way?